# How to make a button to delete a message output cell?

Tags: button, message-coding

I got an error message about the following inputs.

```
Sin[x,y] 
N[Pi, a]
```

[image]

There are two things I want.

(1) Creating a button to delete all message output cells

(2) Set the message output cell to be output in one line unconditionally

Comment: Use `Quiet` - `Sin[x, y] // Quiet`, then there will be no need to delete anything.

Comment: Why do you want to use incorrect syntax and incorrect parameters?

Comment: Quiet doesn't want to. After checking the error message output cell, I try to delete it with a button.

Answer (score 2):

#### (1)

```
Button["Delete Message Cells", 
 NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "Message", All, CellStyle]; 
 NotebookDelete[]; 
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, EvaluationCell]]
```

**Screenshots:**

***Before:***

[image]

***After evaluation of input cells that generate messages:***

[image]

***After clicking the button:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works well in Mathematica. However, the message cell output from the Wolfram Player is not deleted. I hope to work on Wolfram Player.

Comment: Is there a way to get the error message by String in the output cell?

Comment: @Hoony, don't know how to make this work in Wolfram Player.

Comment: I have an Enterprise CDF, so it's possible. However, my question now is that I want to extract the message as expr in a string like 'expr=...messages...' from Mathematica and do the next task.